# G-Suite: How to restrict Youtube 'can approve' on iOS devices for my employees?

Tags: g-suite

Quick summary of the problem:
I'm unable to restrict Youtube watching on iOS devices sufficiently from G-Suite.  Some unapproved videos are still able to be watched.

Detail step-by-step I've taken:
From the Google Admin console, I have 2 employees in a group.  After navigating to the Apps icon, and thereafter the icon Additional Google Services, I select the Youtube option on Page 2.  I have Permissions restricted to the 'Can approve videos' level.  Thereafter I am able to approve videos for my employees to watch.

This works **most** of the time; they are using an iPad, and even though they are logged into their G-suite employee account, they are still able to watch videos that are not on the approved list.

To clarify, they are still not able to watch most of what is on Youtube; however, the specific issue is that they are able to watch some videos that are not on the 'can approve videos' list.
I would appreciate your wisdom in this matter.